# Rectangular select in Eclipse editor as in any Microsoft tools

Tags: eclipse, editor

In Microsoft tools such as Word and Visual Studio, there is a feature to select text in a rectangle manner by pressing the Alt key while selecting. Is there anything like that in Eclipse?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945382/eclipse-plugin-for-rectangular-select-cut-paste-regions, which was for Eclipse 3.4 and asked about the existence of a plugin.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> toggles Block or Column selection mode in Eclipse 3.5 or later.

Other than that you can try the 'Columns 4 Eclipse' Plug-in for Eclipse 3.3.1 [here](http://columns4eclipse.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: But only if you are using Eclipse 3.5 (or newer).

Comment: This does not work for me in Helios when doing Android development (if I press Shift+Alt+A I get 3 options, all related to Android and nothing like column select).

Comment: @Felix same here. So I changed the key in `Window->Preferences->General->Keys` as indicated by afalend's answer.

Comment: Additionally, you can tell you're in Block mode because the pointer is crosshairs.

Answer (score 15):

As another poster noted- the Android ADT blocks the use of Alt+Shift+A. An easy fix is to go to `Window->Preferences->General->Keys` and look for "Toggle Block Selection"

From there, you can assign your own hotkey that will not conflict with the Android tools. For example I tied it to Alt+A, which works just fine.

As others have said, this will not work in Eclipse 3.4 or earlier. I am using Eclipse 3.7.2, YMMV.

Answer (score 6):

For the Mac, use <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> (option+command+A) to toggle between the two selection modes.  Command-Shift-A will give you something quite unexpected.